# I have 5 cars and two drivers, can I cover one car with high liability and the rest with the minimum? California

Tags: california, insurance

We are family with lots of cars, 5 and only two drivers. We switch off depending on what we are doing. Commuting, I drive my 2 seater and wife drives her suv. Family outing we take our big sedan, trip to the boat, we take my suv with tow package.

I'm paying for insurance on each car as if I drove each every day. I like to have good liability coverage in case of an accident and want to cover anyone we might hurt. We keep a high deductible to help with cost. My question is, can I have one car covered with great liability and all of the others with just the minimum and if in an accident with the latter, would my full liability be in play? Is there an insurance that simply follows what car you are driving or better yet just follows who is driving?

Comment: You really should discuss the situation with an insurance representative to make sure that you have the right coverage for each vehicle considering  how they are used.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about financial planning not the law

Comment: What auto insurance may and must cover, adn how policies may be structured is generally tightly regulated at the state level in the US, so whether this is even possible is a matter of law, and this should not be closed as a non-law question.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Car insurance companies typically require the same level of liability on all cars insured through them, so I believe the legal requirements from the state are more forgiving than what the insurer will do. I'm not arguing the question should be closed though.

Comment: @ColleenV  that could be part of a relevant answer. Indeed one possible answer is that the way to do this is to use multiple ins companies. But IMO there is still a legal issue here.

Comment: @David Siegel I see your point, but the OP is asking *"is there an insurance that"* can reduce their premiums which to me appears to be a financial-planning not legal question. A suitable edit along the lines of *what are the legal requirements for multi-car motor insurance* may sway me though.

Comment: In my experience the amount of coverage doesn’t make too much difference in cost.

Comment: Just as an anecdotal observation, auto liability seems to work more or less that way anyway.  That is, insuring a second or third (similar) vehicle costs less than insuring 2 or 3 separately.  Generally you'll be asked about miles driven for each, too.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an insurance that simply follows what car you are driving or better yet just follows who is driving

The answer is simply No.

Unfortunately not!

> can I have one car covered with great liability and all of the others with just the minimum and if in an accident with the latter, would my full liability be in play

1. regarding insurance for paying damage ***to the other person*** (when you hit someone)
2. in Cali. (and essentially, everywhere on Earth), you ***MUST (legally)*** have such insurance on ***every single separate vehicle***. end of story. there's nothing to discuss and no other angle.
3. regarding coverage on "your" vehicle for damage, theft, etc. it's entirely up to you.  you can have none whatsoever, or, total coverage.
4. specifically regarding your situation, it's totally commonplace and insurance companies have "deals" for people with many cars and cars they don't use often. sometimes they're based on low-mileage per year on a certain car etc. Simply shop for a good deal in your specific situation.